# Как нормально сделать форму, почему кнопка не уменьшается

Tags: java, javafx, swing, gui

Как нормально сделать форму, почему кнопка не уменьшается? Как сделать так, чтобы все работало как в Qt designer в c++ или питоне, просто подбешивает, нет свободы действий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно чуть больше информации? В чем проблема, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Свободно передвигать элементы GUI

Comment: Яснопонятно....

Comment: Как убрать layout, spacer мне не дают ничего сдвинуть

Comment: У этого лайаута окна расползаются по всему экрану.